# Selecting dropdown item where only first word matches using Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to select an element from the dropdown.I am adding a new name to the dropdown list, its getting updated by some other name. Suppose if I am trying to add "Foo" to the drodown list, its getting updated by "Foo 123". The 123 is a random number. Is there anything like pattern matching which can be used in Selenium.

The code I am using in C# is:

```
var StyleGroupName = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Name("sgroupnbr"));
StyleGroupName.Click();
var selectelement = new SelectElement(StyleGroupName);
selectelement.SelectByText(GrpName);
```

My TestClass is:

```
  [TestMethod]
  public void Delete_Style_Group()
  {
   StyleGrp.GrpNme("ADRIJA (413)").DeleteStyleGroup();
  }
  [TestInitialize]
  public void ClassInit()
  {
  StyleGrp.Goto();
  StyleGrp.StyltGroupName("Adrija").Configuration("C3 One Tab").Save();
  }
```

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using `IJavascriptExecutor` with partially matching the option text and select as below :

```
var StyleGroupName = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Name("sgroupnbr"));

((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text.indexOf(arguments[1]) != -1){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }", StyleGroupName, GrpName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select an option by matching expressions, the text needs to be exact.

Alternative way to do this would be

```
var selectelement = new SelectElement(StyleGroupName);
foreach (var option in selectelement.Options)
{
   if (option.Text.StartsWith("ADRIJA"))
     {
         option.Click();
         break;
     }
}
```

Reference [SelectElement C# implementation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/support/UI/SelectElement.cs)

Comment: Thank you so much @Prasanna